# How can I change the text of a UIBarButtonItem in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have a BarButton and I have a multi language application so I want to change its name programmatically based the language I have selected.

I drag it from the storyboard to my swift file but I didn't see any function which can change its name.
This is my button:

```
@IBOutlet weak var detailButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show some additional code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you for your answer someone already posted an answer and solved my prblem

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Simply you can set

```
detailButton.title = "Back"  //Whatever you want set here
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are adding a button programmatically in swift 3, you can do it this way (in this example I'm adding a button titled "About" and the selector is a function being triggered):

add an outlet:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var AboutBarButton: UIBarButtonItem!
```

then in view did load, assign the title and functions

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = AboutBarButton
let aboutButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "About", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(AboutBarButtonPressed(_:)))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = aboutButton
```